# JWT Signature verification failed , php to java

Tags: java, php, jwt

I am creating JWT token in PHP using firebase/php-jwt

```
$jwt = JWT::encode($accessToken, base64_encode($apiKey), "HS512");
```

and parse this Jwt token in Java using jwtk/jjwt

```
Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(apiKey).parseClaimsJws(accessToken).getBody();
```

and i am unable to verify the token in java

Comment: Stupid question but are you using the same key (public/private) in php and java?

Comment: yes, i am using same key both in php and java

Comment: Do you get any errors from parsing the jwt token? Have to put it into jwt.io to see if it can be parsed there?

Comment: Probably is an encoding issue with the apiKey. Try `.setSigningKey(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(apiKey))`. It this does not work post a sample token and the used key